# Meaning of => and (Ord a)

Tags: haskell

First of all, please be aware that I looked online (in stackoverflow and Hoogle) to see if I could find anything to this topic!

I have been working myself through a "learn yourself a haskell" and there are two things I have been stumbling upon quite often which I don't really understand. The use of => and (Ord a) in several important functions.

As an example:

```
max :: (Ord a) => a -> a -> a
```

and is the use of "Ordering" the same as (Ord a), as in:

```
compareWith :: Int -> Ordering
```

Thank you for taking your time and helping me with this (probably) simpole question!

Comment: You can *almost* think of `(=>)` as an operator of kind `Constraint -> *`, except a constrained type is not a valid expression outside of a type annotation. (Also, `=>` "takes" either a single `Constraint` or a "tuple" of `Constraint`s.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `=>` symbol is used to build class constraints on a function. In the `max` example, it means that all parameters of type `a` need to implement the `Ord` typeclass.

Consider the implementation of `max`

```hs
max :: (Ord a) => a -> a -> a
max x y = if x < y then y else x
```

The only thing we know about `x` and `y` is that they have to satisfy the `Ord` typeclass. That in turn allows us to use the `<` function for comparison, whose signature is:

```hs
(<) :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
```

If you were to omit the `Ord a` constraint from the definition of `max`, then it wouldn't compile, because the body of `max` wouldn't be able to use the comparison function.

Comment: Here is link to [source](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.19/ghc-prim-0.5.0.0/src/GHC-Classes.html#Ord).

Answer (score 4):

The part `(Ord a) =>` is a type constraint, indicating a is an ordinal type (it can be ordered).

You can read `max :: (Ord a) => a -> a -> a` as:

*where a is an ordinal type, "max" takes 2 arguments of type a and returns type a*